# Selenium does not save whole page source Python

Tags: python, selenium

Ok so I'm trying to save the whole page source of a webpage to a variable and then query the variable to see if it contains a word but when I save the page source to a variable it only saves this for some reason `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`.

I am using this:

```
s = driver.page_source
print(s)
```

It returns just this:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>.
```

Comment: Could you add whole code snippet, please?

Comment: Did you use to open page driver.get("your_link")?

Comment: There could be multiple things. One is that you extract the page source when it is still not loaded. You try to load source and have multiple windows. You could be having issue of using old GeckoDriver/ChromeDriver

Comment: Can you add the page link and the code? It will be easier to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you call driver.page_source before loading the URl.

Please first call

```
 driver.get("yourdesiredurl")
```

Then call the method

```
s = driver.page_source
print(s)
```

Then you will be able to get the full page source.